# Помогите расшифровать и решить ошибку android

Tags: android, android-studio

Я создаю простое приложение галерея для андроид с локальными картинками, то есть я кинул несколько картинок в папку drawable. Но теперь возникла проблема с работой самого приложения, а именно при запуске у меня высвечивается весь список картинок и есть возможность выбора одной из них для просмотра, весь список картинок размещен в виде строки миниатюр, которую можно потянуть для того что бы увидеть следующие элементы списка, но при протягивании этой строки у меня слетает приложение, сначала думал что проблема в версии андроид поэтому выбрал версию 4.1 но все равно приложение крашится, возможно кто то знает что означает моя ошибка и сможет помочь решить мою проблему. Если я не сильно понятно обьяснил свой вопрос я коментах дообъясняю. Ниже вы можете увидеть код ошибки

```
03-18 20:22:36.077 22411-22411/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                   Process: com.example.andrew.myapplication, PID: 22411
                                                   java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 33177612 byte allocation with 16765264 free bytes and 21MB until OOM
                                                       at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
                                                       at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
                                                       at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:609)
                                                       at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:444)
                                                       at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:1080)
                                                       at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2672)
                                                       at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2577)
                                                       at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:814)
                                                       at android.content.Context.getDrawable(Context.java:458)
                                                       at android.widget.ImageView.resolveUri(ImageView.java:813)
                                                       at android.widget.ImageView.setImageResource(ImageView.java:420)
                                                       at com.example.andrew.myapplication.CustomGalleryAdapter.getView(CustomGalleryAdapter.java:40)
                                                       at android.widget.Gallery.makeAndAddView(Gallery.java:868)
                                                       at android.widget.Gallery.fillToGalleryRightLtr(Gallery.java:822)
                                                       at android.widget.Gallery.fillToGalleryRight(Gallery.java:766)
                                                       at android.widget.Gallery.trackMotionScroll(Gallery.java:396)
                                                       at android.widget.Gallery.onScroll(Gallery.java:1046)
                                                       at android.view.GestureDetector.onTouchEvent(GestureDetector.java:669)
                                                       at android.widget.Gallery.onTouchEvent(Gallery.java:961)
                                                       at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:9373)
                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2553)
                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2240)
                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2559)
                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2260)
                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2559)
                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2260)
                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2559)
                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2260)
                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2559)
                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2260)
                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2559)
                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2260)
                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2559)
                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2260)
                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2559)
                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2260)
                                                       at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2453)
                                                       at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1755)
                                                       at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2782)
                                                       at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:68)
                                                       at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2402)
                                                       at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:9614)
                                                       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4463)
                                                       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4319)
                                                       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3843)
                                                       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3902)
                                                       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3868)
                                                       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3998)
                                                       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3876)
                                                       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4055)
                                                       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3848)
                                                       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3902)
                                                    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(View
03-18 20:22:36.077 1932-6047/? E/ActivityManager: App crashed! Process: com.example.andrew.myapplication
```

Comment: И так все ясно из ошибки: out of memory. Слишком жирные картинки, скорее всего, в превью загружаете.

Comment: на устройстве не хватает памяти, чтобы переработать такое количество картинок. их размер слишком большой

Comment: ну это картинки я брал с фона компа, наверное из-за большого разрешения они плохо работают, а вообще для такой задачи какой размер картинки нормальный??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

На самом деле вы можете брать любые картинки просто прежде чем их отображать в списке нужно уменьшить их размер! если используются Glide/Picasso нужно посмотреть соответсвующие методы, иначе можно попробовать так:

```
// считать Drawable из папки в которой они лежат
Drawable oldDrawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.somedrawable);
Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) oldDrawable).getBitmap();
// Привести их к размеру 50 x 50 пикселей
Drawable newDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 50, 50, true));
// Работать уже с newDrawable
```

Надеюсь это поможет!